# Can't interact with browser pop-up with nightwatch.js

Tags: automation, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

This is the last I've tried, but the problem is that once the popup is on the screen, I can't use the Console to get any of the selectors, I only see the html and body tags. PLEASE HELP!

`module.exports = { 'Demo test Google' : function (client) {  client .url('https://practice.expandtesting.com/#examples') client.pause(1000) client.click('#examples > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > h3 > a') client.pause(2000) client.setValue('Username', 'testuser')  client.keys.TAB client.setValue('Password', 'testpass')  client.end(); }  }`

Answer (score 0):

`Selenium` can't interact with a native JS Alert popup (browser popup you mentioned).
Consequently, it is necessary to switch to the JS Alert and utilize the appropriate methods.

Fortunately, `Nightwatch` methods seamlessly handle the switch to JS Alerts, leaving us only to employ the following methods:

[image]

In your case you will need to use `setAlertText()` and then accept the JS Alert after you're done using `acceptAlert()`;

Source:
https://nightwatchjs.org/v26/api/setAlertText.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying!
At that moment I didn't notice (I'm new in automation and Nightwatch as well), but it is not a JS Alert, pop up, it is a Prompt, as far as I know, I found that info you mentioned before and tried it and did not work for that case. It did work for another excercise I was stucked on, which it was indeed a JS Alert